# How to correctly use static boolean inside of static methods

Tags: android, static, boolean

So, I need to use this method to return either true or false, but I'm facing a problem with my global static boolean as its value isn't being set correctly.

```
private static boolean mIsAvailable = false;

    public static boolean isAvailable(final int language){

        //create model for the language
        final FirebaseTranslateRemoteModel lnModel =
                new FirebaseTranslateRemoteModel.Builder(LanguageSetterUtil.setTranslationLanguage(language))
                        .build();

        modelManager.isModelDownloaded(lnModel)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Boolean aBoolean) {

                        mIsAvailable = aBoolean;
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // Error.

                        mIsAvailable = false;

                    }
                })
                .addOnCanceledListener(new OnCanceledListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCanceled() {

                        mIsAvailable = false;

                    }
                });

        return mIsAvailable;
    }
```

I tried making the methods not static but of course that affects other methods that I don't want to change. And I can't use a listener inside a static method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is fully logical. In your method you **do not** actually change the value of variable at all - you just set listeners there. And after just returning the previous value of your boolean var.
You can create interface for example

```
interface Callback {
    void onResult(boolean result)
}
```

And then change your isAvailable method to

```
public static void isAvailable(int language, Callback callback)
```

and instead of `mIsAvailable = aBoolean;` you call `callback.onResult(aBoolean);`
So you don't need your boolean var anymore and you can remove it.
Now to get boolean value you should pass callback to your function:

```
isAvailable(1, available -> {
    // Use your boolean available as you need here
})
```

Comment: So, how can I deal with that? How can I change the actual value of the boolean or return the updated value? And Isn't using a static value means that there can't be different versions of the variable in the memory, why does that happen?